# Scroll to top after slideDown

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I have made small jquery collapse/expand script

http://jsfiddle.net/goldie/QFL49/
(please don't pay attenton to html/css code because I did'n made it)

How can I make expanded div to scroll to the top of the page?
Thank you for help.

Comment: do you want the top of the expanded div to be be always on top of the viewport?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found it

```
.slideDown(200, function() {
    $('html, body').delay('200').animate({
    scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 111
    }, 200);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Found this in the end, works fine:

```
.slideDown(200, function() {
    $('html, body').delay('200').animate({
    scrollTop: $(this).offset().top 
    }, 200); }); } });
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use .scrollTop or if you want it animated, do .animate({"top": "0px"},1000) for example

Comment: I already did that. $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().next().animate({"top": "0px"},1000); and it doesn't work

Comment: @Goldie - that is horribly ugly and unstable!  Try `$(this).closest('.someClass')` instead.

Comment: I tried even that but it simply doesn't work :) here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/goldie/QFL49/ you can try by yourself

Comment: if what you want is to send the clicked section to the top, here's what I'd do...`$(this).closest(".aktuell-wrapper").prependTo('#a')` (I gave the td an id of 'a' for simplicity)  I did it in http://jsfiddle.net/QFL49/1/

Comment: @Rodolfo
That is what I want - to send the clicked section on the top, but I don't see that it's working on http://jsfiddle.net/QFL49/1/

Comment: well it's adding it, you may want to move the scrollbar to the top by doing a `$(window).scrollTop(0)` after that

Comment: errrrrrrm no :) In that case, if you click some of the sections which are on the bottom, page will scroll on the top and opened article will not be visible.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the jQuery scrollTo plugin, http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo

Comment: Although I have already used ScrollTo before somehow here it doesn't work at all